# Existence of a one-dimensional representation

Tags: representation-theory

I am working on the following exercise in relation to representation theory and I have some questions.

Let $G$ be a group with center $Z$. Let $\pi$ be an irreducible complex representation of G on a finite dimensional complex vector space $V$. Prove that for each $z \in Z$, $\pi (z)$ is an endomorphism of $V$ that is for all $g \in G$ we have that $\pi (g) \pi (z) = \pi (z) \pi (g)$. Conclude that there exists a one-dimensional representation $\chi_{\pi} : Z \to \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ of $Z$ such that $\pi (z) = \chi_{\pi} (z)\operatorname{id}_V$ for all $z \in Z$

My idea for an answer is: By definition we have that the center $Z$ of $G$ is given as $Z:= \lbrace z \in G : zg=gz,\,\forall g \in G \rbrace$. Let $g \in G$ and $z \in Z$ and let $\pi$ be a complex and irreducible representation. Then we obtain that

\begin{align*}
\pi (g) \pi (z) &= \pi (gz) \\
&= \pi (zg) \\
&= \pi (z) \pi (g) 
\end{align*}

Where it has been used that $\pi$ is a representation (so $\pi (g) \pi (z) = \pi (gz)$) and that $z \in Z$. We have now shown that $\pi (z)$ is an endomorphism. Is this a correct approach or is there more to it which I am missing?

Additionally I am not sure how to conclude the second part of the question.

Comment: What is $\,T\,$ here? Is it a typo for $\,V$?

Comment: I have just corrected it, thank you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your approach to the first part if fine.

If $z\in Z$, consider the kernel of $\pi(z)$. It is stable with respect to the action $\pi$ of $G$. But that's an irreducible representation. Therefore, $\ker\pi(z)=\{0\}$ (in which case $\pi(z)$ is injective) or $\ker\pi(z)$ is $V$ (in which case $\pi(z)$ is the null function). Since $V$ is a finite-dimensional complex vector space, $\pi(z)$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda$. But $\pi(z)-\lambda\operatorname{Id}$ commutes with every $\pi(g)$. So, by the same argument as before, $\ker\bigl(\pi(z)-\lambda\operatorname{Id}\bigr)=0$ or $\ker\bigl(\pi(z)-\lambda\operatorname{Id}\bigr)=V$. But it cannot be $\{0\}$, since $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, and therefore $\pi(z)=\lambda\operatorname{Id}$.

So, this proves that, for each $z\in Z$, there is some scalar $\lambda_z$ such that $\pi(z)=\lambda_z\operatorname{Id}$. But $\pi(z)$ is invertible, and therefore $\lambda_z\ne0$. So, take $\chi_\pi(z)=\lambda_z$.